# How to test facebook signed requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, unit-testing, testing, oauth

I have a facebook app that makes use of signed requests for inviting people to different parts of our page. It seems to work more or less ok, but as a Rails developer I am feeling kind of uneasy not being able to test a feature... Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a Test API from facebook  for signed requests (only Test User API).
Are there still any recommended ways on how to test facebook signed request handling?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of libraries out there for parsing it.

We also have this endpoint that will parse the request and show you the content, but it won't test the signature since it doesn't have your api key or secret.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo?signed_request=aJsF49izIkIWo35HMCU6bBflIcZ870-9nwWc-1UJD64.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTI4ODk0NzkxOSwidGhlIGFuc3dlciI6NDJ9